# Mulplicity Roots of the characteristic polynomial and the dimension of the characteristic space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V$ be a n-dimensional space and T a linear operator diagonalizable on $V$. If $c_{1}, ..., c_{k}$ are characteristics values of vector space V, $W_{i}$ are the characteristic space associated the characteristic value $c_{i}$ and $f(x)=(x-c_{1})^{d_{1}}...(x-c_{k})^{d_{k}}$ is the polynomial characteristic of $T$, then $(dim W_{i})=d_{i}$.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$W_i=\ker((T-c_i\operatorname{id})^{d_i})$$
and by the primary decomposition theorem

$$V=\oplus_{i=1}^k W_i$$
and let $\alpha_i=\dim W_i$ so the restriction $T_i$ of $T$ to $W_i$ is trigonalizable and we see easily that $$\chi_{T_i}(x)=(x-c_i)^{\alpha_i}$$

so since

$$f(x)=\chi_T(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k\chi_{T_i}(x)$$
then we get $\alpha_i=d_i$.

Comment: Actually the question says $T$ is diagonalisable; a rather boring case.

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious, considering a basis$~B$ of eigenvectors which is assumed to exist: $W_i$ is spanned by those vectors of$~B$ with eigenvalue$~c_i$, and since the corresponding entries of the diagonal matrix of$~T$ with respect to the basis$~B$ are all $c_i$, one gets a factor $(X-c_i)^{\dim W_i}$ in the characteristic polynomial of$~T$.

---

It is somewhat more interesting with the diagonalisable assumption replaced just by the characteristic polynomial being split, in which case the result still holds if "[characteristic subspace](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-espace_caract%C3%A9ristique)" is taken to mean "[generalised eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector)" (which I always thought it did, although it appears that some take it to be a mere synonym for eigenspace). I will therefore assume that $W_i$ is the generalised eigenspace for$~c_i$. The fact that the characteristic polynomial is split means there is a direct sum decomposition $V=\bigoplus_iW_i$.

By the definition of generalised eigenspace subspace$~W_i$ for $c_i$, the restriction of $T-c_iI$ to$~W_i$ is nilpotent. On an appropriate basis of$~W_i$, this restriction of$~T$ therefore has an upper triangular matrix, with diagonal entries all $c_i$; the characteristic polynomial of the restriction then is $(X-c_i)^{\dim W_i}$. By the mentioned direct sum decomposition, the characteristic polynomial of$~T$ then is $\prod_i(X-c_i)^{\dim W_i}$.